# Need to know the language of cod

Tags: php, curl

i want some help to know the language of code

can u tell in which language you make this code? I want to use izooto api and they gave me example code

Following is sample code

```
curl -X POST \        
 - H "Authentication-Token: abc123efgh456ijklmn9786" \
 - H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{
 "title" : "Limited Period Offer",
 "message" : "Go Shopping, Save Big",
 "icon_url" : "https://yourdomain.com/icon.png",
 "banner_url" : "https://yourdomain.com/large-image.png",
 "landing_url" : "https://yourdomain.com/offers",
 "actions" : [
 {
 "text" : "Buy Now",
 "url" : "https://yourdomain.com/buy-now"
 },
 {
 "text" : "Compare",
 "url" : "https://yourdomain.com/compare"
 }],
 "utm_source" : "izooto",
 "utm_medium" : "push_notification",
 "utm_campaign" : "promotion",
 "ttl" : "86400",
 "target" : {
 "type" : "all"
 }
 }' "https://apis.izooto.com/v1/notifications"
```

but i do not know how and where to use. its in PHP or which langauge?

I want to use this code in PHP. can anyone help me

Comment: Curl PHP posting in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not a programming language code block**. It is a [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request using [CURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). So if you want to make this request to PHP(*which is a server side programming language*), you can try a simple online tool that makes your CURL request to PHP easily.I've converted your HTTP POST using that online [tool](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) and then did **slight modification**

Also SEE the manuals for [PHP CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php)

```
 // Generated by POSTMAN client
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://apis.izooto.com/v1/notifications",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"title\": \"Limited Period Offer\",\n  \"message\": \"Go Shopping, Save Big\",\n  \"icon_url\": \"https://yourdomain.com/icon.png\",\n  \"banner_url\": \"https://yourdomain.com/large-image.png\",\n  \"landing_url\": \"https://yourdomain.com/offers\",\n  \"actions\": [\n    {\n      \"text\": \"Buy Now\",\n      \"url\": \"https://yourdomain.com/buy-now\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"text\": \"Compare\",\n      \"url\": \"https://yourdomain.com/compare\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"utm_source\": \"izooto\",\n  \"utm_medium\": \"push_notification\",\n  \"utm_campaign\": \"promotion\",\n  \"ttl\": \"86400\",\n  \"target\": {\n    \"type\": \"all\"\n  }\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authentication-Token: abc123efgh456ijklmn9786",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));` $data - is an array or object which is passing through this post.

Comment: @Bira agreed sir, I was thinking of that,  Thanks for pointing me out

Comment: but how to use Authentication-Token in your php code? you did not used it

Comment: you guys just convert using tool but where to put this auth code and other things as this code is not working

Comment: @gaurav on your question you didn't mention about the authentication process/credential. If you did that then I might add that part also

Comment: hello that was in starting of my code : curl -X POST \        
 - H "Authentication-Token: abc123efgh456ijklmn9786" \
 - H "Content-Type: application/json" \ . can you proper modifuy my code in php which can run proper. i need it urgent. kindly help

Comment: but that code is in first 2 lines. can you pleasse modify my code usng auth code and let it work proper?

Comment: @gaurav sorry bro. for being late, I've *Edited* my answer. Have a look again and let me know is that working or not now?

Comment: i use your code. put all informaton proper and at end i am getting {"success":false,"message":"Invalid request parameters"}

Comment: also if i want to use that code without php using only curl then how i can and wher to use that code

Comment: you need to replace `"Authentication-Token: abc123efgh456ijklmn9786",` with proper authentication value